# How to query Unicode characters from SQL Server 2008

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

With `NVARCHAR` data type, I store my local language text in a column. I face a problem how to query that value from the database.

- ዜናገብርኤልስ is stored value.

I wrote SQL like this

```
select DivisionName 
from t_Et_Divisions 
where DivisionName = 'ዜናገብርኤልስ'

select unicode (DivisionName) 
from t_Et_Divisions 
where DivisionName = 'ዜናገብርኤልስ'
```

The above didn't work. Does anyone have any ideas how to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: I do hope you are not on a slippery slope here... You shouldn't compose sql queries in C# with parameters (your `ዜናገብርኤልስ`)... you should use the `SqlParameter` object. That will implicitly solve all the unicode problems plus many other problems.

Comment: Dear, did you get my question first? am not asking you how to manipulate unicode characters in C#. am asking you how to query specific stored non english character from DB.

Comment: Yes... And I see you have tagged your question asp.net . So you don't seem to want to execute the query directly in the SQL Management Studio. So you want to execute the query from your program. So my warning is perfectly ok.

Comment: I understand your point. but before am going to C#, first i need to check the exact query from Sql Server management studio. that is why. n ways thanx alot.

Answer (score 3):

You need to prefix your Unicode string literals with a `N`:

```
select DivisionName 
from t_Et_Divisions 
where DivisionName = N'ዜናገብርኤልስ'
```

This `N` prefix tells SQL Server to treat this string literal as a Unicode string and not convert it to a non-Unicode string (as it will if you omit the `N` prefix).

**Update:**

I still fail to understand what is not working according to you....

I tried setting up a table with an NVARCHAR column, and if I select, I get back that one, exact row match - as expected:

```
DECLARE @test TABLE (DivisionName NVARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @test (DivisionName)
VALUES (N'ዜናገብርኤልስ'), (N'ዜናገብርኤልስ,ኔትዎርክ,ከስተመር ስርቪስ'), (N'ኔትዎርክ,ከስተመር ስርቪስ')

SELECT * 
FROM @test
WHERE DivisionName = N'ዜናገብርኤልስ'
```

This returns **exactly one row** - what else are you seeing, or what else are you expecting??

**Update #2:**

Ah - I see - the columns contains **multiple, comma-separated** values - which is a horrible design mistake to begin with..... (violates **first normal form** of database design - **don't do it!!**)

And then you want to select all rows that *contain* that search term - but only display the search term itself, not the whole `DivisionName` column? Seems rather pointless..... try this:

```
select N'ዜናገብርኤልስ'
from t_Et_Divisions 
where DivisionName LIKE N'%ዜናገብርኤልስ%'
```

The `LIKE` searches for rows that *contain* that value, and since you already know what you want to display, just put that value into the `SELECT` list ....

Comment: thank you for your quick response. i tried your query, but it will generate all the unicode characters that stored in DB, I need only to display this specific unicode character.

Comment: I'm sorry - I don't understand what you're saying - does this query work - or not?? I don't understand what you mean by *generate all the unicode characters* ? The query doesn't *generate* anything ......

Comment: i mean to say. i have 3 Nvarchar data type record in the table. when i execute the query, all 3 records will be generate. but i need only one record since i used where condition.

Comment: Do all those 3 rows have this value for `DivisionName`? Then **of course** all three of them are returned - that's how SQL `SELECT` works!

Comment: see, in DivisionName column you will have three value{ዜናገብርኤልስ,ኔትዎርክ,ከስተመር ስርቪስ} my question is how can you retrieve only ዜናገብርኤልስ ?

Comment: i understand = operator will find the exact match. but i need to query only one Unicode value, Like will find more data not single data. see i tried this query "select DivisionName 
from t_Et_Divisions 
where DivisionName Like N'ዜናገብርኤልስ'" , the query generate two records{ኔትዎርክ,ዜናገብርኤልስ} but i need to get only {ዜናገብርኤልስ} . i hope you will get my idea.

Comment: i don't know how shall explain my problem. lets try one time. i have table having column DivisionName. the column will store Nvarchar data type Unicode values{ዜናገብርኤልስ,ኔትዎርክ,ከስተመር ስርቪስ}. then i need to query only value ዜናገብርኤልስ. i tried = operator but it will generate all values{ዜናገብርኤልስ,ኔትዎርክ,ከስተመር ስርቪስ} and i tried LIKE but it will generate{ኔትዎርክ,ዜናገብርኤልስ}. how can i query only ዜናገብርኤልስ ? . = and LIKE is not working?  it is not clear ?

Comment: @Sapna - can you create a [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6) to explain your problem

Comment: Thank you all for your support. finally its working using the below query.          SELECT *
FROM   t_Et_Divisions
WHERE  DivisionName = N'ዜናገብርኤልስ ' COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS;